# Why producer.send(record).get() works but producer.send(record, callback) does not work

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm using kafka to send messages to a consumer. But for some reason when I send a record into a topic with `producer.send(record, new MyProducerCallback());` the consumer for that topic does not receive the record. However, when I send a record by using `RecordMetadata m = producer.send(record).get();`, the record arrives perfectly at the consumer. The callback method used to work but it doesn't anymore. Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 2):

Your Callback will get triggered in a background thread, meanwhile you're not blocking the main thread, so the program is able to end without executing it.

If you want to ensure that your Callback will be called, you'll either have to

1. `.send().get()` the Future
2. `Thread.sleep()` the main thread.

And don't forget to `close()` the Producer object

Comment: But even if the callback is triggered in the background thread, when why is the record never put into the queue. I left the consumer running for ages and no record ever came through?

Comment: The main thread exits before the Callback is able to be executed in the background. I don't know why you're not seeing a produced record, but I'm just telling you my experience using the same methods

Comment: when you use the async send, the Producer put the message into an internal queue because it sends messages in batch with a background thread doing that. If your main thread exits immediately, the background thread have no time to get message from the internal queue and sending it to the broker. As I suggested in my answer, having the code on how you are using the Producer in the main application could be really helpful.

Comment: @cod3min3 That comment was for you

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the producer application ends before your Kafka producer was able to put the message in the internal queue and then having enough time for sending the message asynchronously in background. With the synchronous send you are blocking the main thread until the producer receives the ack from the broker. Can you share the code how are you using the producer.send() with the callback please?

Comment: How do you "check the internal queue"?

Comment: you can't afaik. But I'm asking for the main thread code to see if the main thread is blocked enough for the producer.